# Assign 1 cpu core to 1 thread c++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a process which create 3 threads. I want to assign 1 thread to 1 cpu core (CPU has 8 physical cores) and those cores only run my threads. Because i want to make sure my computation thread always run with highest priority.

For example: Thread 1 is assigned to core 1, and core 1 is only run thread 1. Core 0,2,3,4,5,6,7 is freely to run others threads from others processes.

Does any library support this? or anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What OS do you use? In linux, see manual page for `sched_setaffinity`.

Comment: thank gudok, i use windows 7.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? BTW, you should **edit your question**, first by tagging it with Windows, and also by giving motivations. Don't answer in comments, but by editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally called processor or thread affinity and is something you probably will have the handle at the platform level.

On windows, you can use the [SetThreadAffinityMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Exactly what i want is after assigned, cpu core only run my thread. Does SetThreadAffinityMask help this?

Comment: It depends on what you mean, if you mean that your thread is the only thread in the entire system that the OS will schedule on that core, then no, I don't think that is possible, other processes will also be scheduled on it. However if you assign your other theads to the other cores, they will never run on it.

Comment: You could set SetThreadAffinityMask for *every* process running on your system to exclude one core to achieve this. At least in theory.

Comment: Better use thread and process priorities if you want your thread to run more than other apps. Read about SetThreadPriority and SetPriorityClass.

Comment: Good read on the windows scheduler: http://cbloomrants.blogspot.se/2010/09/09-12-10-defficiency-of-windows-multi.html

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you have sched_setaffinity and sched_getaffinity. http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity

Answer (score 0):

Apart from SetThreadAffinityMask, there is also SetThreadIdealProcessor which is a bit more forgiving in case you make bad decisions on which core you run it on (i.e. several cpu-hungry apps locked to the same core).